# Convert objective-c array to lowercase and not have the extra formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to convert an array to lower case for comparisons (e.g., using intersect).  My question is how do I convert the array to lowercase and not have the extra formatting.  In other words, how do I get the same NSLog result?  I've tried using `NSData` and `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]` and running a loop instead of using the description. I've even tried loading the data from .csv, but no matter what I end up with the (\n extras.

```
NSArray *arrayT = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Awesome", @"enjoy", @"Analysis", nil];
NSArray *arrayT2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Alpha", @"Awesome", @"Name", @"ANALYSIS", @"analysis", nil];

NSString * arrayTowords = [arrayT description];
NSString * arrayTowords2 = [arrayT2 description];


NSLog(@"%@", arrayTowords);
NSLog(@"%@", arrayTowords2);

NSString *lowerT = [arrayTowords lowercaseString];
NSString *lowerT2 = [arrayTowords2 lowercaseString];

NSMutableArray *arrayNEWT = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[lowerT componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]]];
NSMutableArray *arrayNEWT2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[lowerT2 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]]];

NSLog(@"%@", arrayNEWT);
NSLog(@"%@", arrayNEWT2);
```

```
2016-01-25 18:59:29.647 TextCruncher[1191:16284] (
    Awesome,
    enjoy,
    Analysis
)
2016-01-25 18:59:29.647 TextCruncher[1191:16284] (
    Alpha,
    Awesome,
    Name,
    ANALYSIS,
    analysis
)
2016-01-25 18:59:29.648 TextCruncher[1191:16284] (
    "(\n    awesome",
    "\n    enjoy",
    "\n    analysis\n)"
)
2016-01-25 18:59:29.648 TextCruncher[1191:16284] (
    "(\n    alpha",
    "\n    awesome",
    "\n    name",
    "\n    analysis",
    "\n    analysis\n)"
```

Comment: Never use the `description` method for anything other than debugging and log output. It's output is not meant to be used or processed for any other purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution is to create a new array by iterating the original array. Convert each string to lowercase and add it to the new array.

```
NSArray *arrayT = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Awesome", @"enjoy", @"Analysis", nil];
NSArray *arrayT2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Alpha", @"Awesome", @"Name", @"ANALYSIS", @"analysis", nil];

NSMutableArray *lowerT = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *lowerT2 = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *str in arrayT) {
    [lowerT addObject:[str lowercaseString]];
}
for (NSString *str in arrayT2) {
    [lowerT2 addObject:[str lowercaseString]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and spot-on advice.  I had previously used an iteration loop, but that hadn't worked; however, yours works perfectly!

Comment: The dot notation is preferred this days: `str.lowercaseString`.

Comment: @Cristik That's a preference. Even the docs for `lowercaseString` use the method call syntax. All a leftover from when `lowercaseString` used to be a method and not a read-only property.

Comment: Apple (and not only) recommends to switch to the dot syntax, among other things, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html) reference. And if we're talking about the documentation, [lowercaseString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/lowercaseString) is presented as a property there (though as you said the examples still use the method call syntax)